# Conditional class inheritance for rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, inheritance, model

I have a multi-tenant rails app up and running.
Models that i want scoped to the current tenant (like this article model here) inherit the tenantscoped model like this

```
class Article < TenantScoped

end
```

this works great. i only recieve objects scoped to the current tenant.

but now im creating an admin interface where i want to be able to add articles to all tenants. but my admin interface is acting as a tenant and the models are being scoped to it.
Which ends with no entries being shown.

I am proposing that the best solution to this is to conditionally inherit from the tenant scoped model like this

```
class Article

  unless SudoTenant.current?
    < TenantScoped
  else
    < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

end
```

i've been searching around to conditional inheritance for ruby classes and havent found anything yet. my syntax is wrong here or is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not possible. You could conditionally include modules based on a state condition, but not inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the class using the block syntax:

```
if SudoTenant.current?
  Article = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
    # your code
  end
else
  Article = Class.new(TenantScoped) do
    # your code
  end
end
```

I strongly recommend to use mixins instead of conditionally inheriting, it's cleaner, clearer and more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking, but I happen to be doing the *same* thing (global articles on a tenant app), and I just created a Tenant for Admin for using it in my global Articles.

I've got something like this:

```
#article.rb
def self.global
  unscoped.where(:company => Company.admin)
end


#company.rb
def self.admin
  where(:name => 'admin').first # this can pretty much be anything that fits to you.
end
```